# How to test nuget packages without officially publishing?

Tags: nuget

If I have one repo that holds libraries (that are published to Nuget) and a separate repo that holds the application code (that consumes the Nuget packages), is there an easy way to test changes to the library code within the application repo without publishing to the official Nuget feed?

Comment: Publish to a private feed?

Comment: What would the workflow look like for that? I imagine: update nuget.config with private feed (need to remove later), point all packages.config to the version on the private feed. Is there an easy way to do all of this? Looking for a solution with the least amount of resistance.

Comment: Your NuGet config or Visual Studio Nuget  package settings would include both public and private sources.  Create a branch for the application code and update to the new version (that initially only exists in the private feed).  Test and if all OK publish to the public feed. You can also mark packages as being pre-release, whether on the private or public feed is up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build script could be something like this

step 1. build your package and copy your `.nupkg`'s to `%buildroot%\newPackages\`

step 2. create a nuget.config file in your application code's root that adds `%buildroot%\newPackages\` as a packageSource. If your application code is a functional test, then you can probably check in the nuget.config, so it doesn't need to be recreated by the build machine every build.

step 3. Have a shell script or small program that updates your application code's references to the newly built package, to match the version that was just built

step 4 build/test your applicationCode